# Excluding an aspect from specific implementations of a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, postsharp

Say I have a generic class:

```
public abstract class MyClass<T> {
    // Contents
}
```

How can I specify an exclude for my aspect for only certain types of T?  I am adding aspects in ithe AssemblyInfo.cs, like so:

```
[assembly: LogMethod(AttributePriority = 0,
                     AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public,
                     AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public,
                     AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to apply generic arguments filtering in a declarative way. For advanced filtering of the aspect targets you can override [CompileTimeValidate](http://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-validation) method on your aspect and filter programmatically.

However, even this is not going to be enough in the case you've described. Let's say you've applied the aspect to a method in `MyClass<T>`. At this point in compilation the T is not known yet, so it's not possible to perform the check. The concrete T is known when a field or variable of `MyClass<T>` is declared somewhere else in the code.

The best option I can see in your case is to make the aspect [instance-scoped](http://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-lifetime) and validate at run-time for each instance of the target class. You can find the sample implementation of this approach below.

```
[PSerializable]
public class LogMethodAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect, IInstanceScopedAspect
{
    private bool disabled;

    public override void OnEntry( MethodExecutionArgs args )
    {
        if ( !this.disabled )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "OnEntry: {0}({1})", args.Method.Name, args.Arguments.GetArgument( 0 ) );
        }
    }

    public object CreateInstance( AdviceArgs adviceArgs )
    {
        LogMethodAttribute clone = (LogMethodAttribute) this.MemberwiseClone();

        Type type = adviceArgs.Instance.GetType();
        if ( type.IsGenericType )
        {
            Type[] genericArguments = type.GetGenericArguments();
            // Filter out targets where T is string.
            if ( genericArguments[0] == typeof( string ) )
            {
                clone.disabled = true;
            }
        }

        return clone;
    }

    public void RuntimeInitializeInstance()
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var obj1 = new Class1<int>();
        obj1.Method1(1);

        var obj2 = new Class1<string>();
        obj2.Method1("a");
    }
}

[LogMethod(AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method)]
public class Class1<T>
{
    public void Method1(T a)
    {
    }
}
```